# Trajectory prediction for the ball getting hit by another ball

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a prediction path for the ball getting hit by another ball.

Below is my code

MainCueball.cs

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 reduceTransPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 2f, transform.position.z);

    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, -transform.forward);

    if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, cueBallRadius, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            lineRender.enabled = true;

            lineRender.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            lineRender.SetPosition(1, -transform.forward + new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y + 1f, hit.point.z));

            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("OtherCueBall"))
            {
                Vector3 newDirection = (hit.transform.position - hit.point).normalized;

                hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<OtherCueBallTrajectory>().DrawPredictionLine(newDirection);
            }
       }
    }
}
```

OtherBallTrajectory.cs

```
private LineRenderer lineRender;

private void Awake()
{
    lineRender = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
}

public void DrawPredictionLine(Vector3 targetDestination)
{
    lineRender.enabled = true;

    lineRender.SetPosition(0, transform.position);

    lineRender.SetPosition(1, targetDestination);
}
```

[image]

As you can see above the second prediction path is not accurate it's pointing on the left side when it should be pointing in the center

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by using Vector3 newDirection =
Vector3.Reflect(hit.transform.position, hit.normal);